# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when loading fixtures

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I built a PatientOrderFixture class to load data using Doctrine fixtures and faker. I'm getting the error 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' when running doctrine:fixtures:load. I've tried reducing it down to just loading a patient object and still get the error, so I added more object to see if maybe it was getting hung up on a required field somewhere.

Loader.php error
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I don't have a foreach in my code, so I'm thinking this is some internal error. Maybe based on the way my fixture is setup?

PatientOrderFixtures.php

```
class PatientOrderFixtures extends Fixture implements FixtureGroupInterface {

    /** @var Generator */
    protected $faker;

    private static $sex = [
        'M',
        'F'
    ];

    private static $race = [
        'American Indian or Alaska Native',
        'Asian',
        'Black or African American',
        'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander',
        'White'
    ];

    private static $ethnicity = [
        'Not Hispanic-Latino-Spanish Origin',
        'Hispanic-Latino-Spanish Origin'
    ];

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->faker = Factory::create();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {

            $user = new User();
            $user
                ->setUsername($this->faker->userName)
                ->setPassword('test')
                ->setRoles(null);
            $manager->persist($user);

            $patient = new Patient();
            $patient
                ->setFirstName($this->faker->firstName)
                ->setMiddleName($this->faker->firstName)
                ->setLastName($this->faker->lastName)
                ->setDateOfBirth($this->faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '-75 years', $endDate = '-1 days'))
                ->setSex($this->faker->randomElement(self::$sex))
                ->setRace($this->faker->randomElement(self::$race))
                ->setEthnicity($this->faker->randomElement(self::$ethnicity))
                ->setZip($this->faker->postcode)
                ->setMRN($this->faker->randomNumber($nbDigits = 8, $strict = false));
            $manager->persist($patient);

            $patientSample = new PatientSample();
            $patientSample
                ->setPatient($patient)
                ->setEnteredDate($this->faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate= '-14 days', $endDate = '-1 days'))
                ->setUser($user);
            $manager->persist($patientSample);

            $patientOrder = new PatientOrder();
            $patientOrder
                ->setAccessionNumber($this->faker->randomNumber($nbDigits = 8, $strict = false))
                ->setPatient($patient)
                ->setPatientSample($patientSample);
            $manager->persist($patientOrder);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
```

```
    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()', make sure you are passing an array in your foreach loop.

Comment: @OmarAbbas Sorry I need to edit this, there error is not coming from a file I created. I get the error when running doctrine:fixtures in line 137 of Loader.php.

Comment: Please could you give us the implementation of setRoles method of User object ?

Comment: @WilliamBridge I've updated it with the function - adding a user was my last change and in my getRoles function I have the default $roles[]='ROLE_USER'.

Comment: I did a test in another fixture.php file of just patient data. It threw the same error until I removed the for loop, so this gives me something to look at at least.

Comment: @BrianBarrick could you give us full path of the "Loader.php" (in which vendor) to check it